# Execute a piece of code for few seconds/minutes with the button?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, nstimer

I just want to run a certain method for 20 seconds when user presses start button and stop it by it's own rather than using a button to do it. But it should also trigger when ever the user press start button  after 20 seconds in next turn.
How can i use NStimer to implement this? 
Sorry for not posting any codes
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "run for 20 seconds"? How often should it run in those 20 seconds? Maybe giving us an idea of what you're actually trying to do helps in figuring out what the best approach is to solve this problem.

Comment: it's a piece of code that i used to calibrate iphone acceleration. I want my calibration function to start after 5 seconds when user press start button. Then execute the calibration code for 20 seconds and stop by it's own without using another button to stop it. Here the readings will be stored in a array.

Comment: As you've guessed, `NSTimer` is what you want to use. What part of `NSTimer` are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually i dnt have any idea to use NStimer to execute the code for 20  seconds and stop it's execution after word. The difficult part of the question. :)

Comment: @user1118321 - I think with the following code it's possible, using the uderinfo to stop the function. But no idea ... Can u help me?  + (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats

Comment: Without more code, it's really hard to help. Do you have an object which does the calibration? If so, you could call the class method you mention above and pass a pointer to your calibration object as the target, and its stop method as the selector. You wouldn't even need any user info. Just reading the docs on `NSTimer` should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: @DavidH - I have accepted all the correct answers and have given them possible credits! If possible please ans me! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Assume ARC - otherwise do the proper retains/releases
{
    NSTimer *timer; // keep a reference around so you can cancel the timer if you need to
    NSDate *timerDate;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // disable button til the time has passed
    [sender setEnabled:NO];

    // make sure its diabled til we're done here
    timerDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval interval = 1; // 1 gets you a callback every second. If you just wnat to wait 20 seconds change it
    // schedule it
    timer = [NSTimer ]scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(myTimeRoutine:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)myTimeRoutine:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    // do something ...

    NSTimeInterval interval = -[timerDate timeIntervalSinceNow]; // return value will be negative, so change sign
    if(interval >= 20) {
        // I'm done now
        myButton.enabled = YES; // so it can be tapped again
        [timer cancel];         // dont want to get any more messages
        timer = nil;            // ARC way to release it
        timerDate = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt implement this on my code yet! But still i accept you answer as you are the 1st person who answered me with the one of the greatest ways! Even going through this, makes me feel like ur a great teacher. Thank you sir! May all ur dreams come true!

Comment: Sam, sincerely, thank you for your kind comments! If you have issues or questions just repost them as a comment and I will see them. Someday you can be a great teacher too!

Comment: I guess, (timer = [NSTimer ]scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time ) here time should be replaced by interval and when i run the code program terminates at this particular line giving the error,[ViewController' myTimeRoutine]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a4b0. What am i doing wrong to get a such an error?

Comment: Make sure you @selector statement has ':' at the end, and the method is exactly as I wrote. the error means that the system could not find a method in your class that matched what you specified when you created the timer.